# Nautilus crash with segmentation fault when opening a folder

Tags: linux, nautilus

I'm running Debian 8.1, GNOME 3.14.1 with Nautilus 3.14.1-2.

Nautilus has crashed for me in the past, today I tried to understand the problem. I work with a lot of geodata and my folder ~/Geodata/GIS_Projects/ProjectName/1848.Survey/ containing: a pdf, a jpg, several JP2s, some georeferenced GTiffs, and another folder (of standard tiffs) crashes upon opening. Here is the ouptut when run from the terminal:

```
valerie@debgis:~$ nautilus
warning: not enough tile data (2 bytes)
Segmentation fault
```

The second line is repeated 246 times.

`ls` has no problem listing the contents of the folder.

How do I figure out the problem? Is this a known bug? Could it be my image files? Is there a better way for me to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you checked your RAM for errors?

Comment: It could be your [jp2 files](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-problem-with-gdal-translate-jp2-file-from-the-usgs-linux-td5137002.html)...

Comment: I used memtest 86+ to check my RAM for errors, there were no problems. @don_crissti they were the problems. Is this a known error with nautilus? Does it not play nice with the new format?

Comment: It has nothing to do with nautilus imo but rather the libs that are used underneath, just read the discussion in that link.

Comment: Skipped reading it before, and sorry for that! So, nautilus is dependent on a jpeg-handling library that does a poor job at handling JPEG2000s which crashes it, is that right? The conversation on the link is about GDAL and it mentioned three libraries, libjpeg, libjasper, and libopenjpeg. All of these are installed on my debian and nautilus doesn't depend directly on any of them, so the faulty lib is in the dependency tree? So, there's no real solution to the problem of nautilus handling JPEG2000s without crashing until the library is fixed. (Unless I want to switch distros or compile myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running the `identify` command from `imagemagick` on each
file holding an image. It may detect the corrupt file.

Otherwise, if nautilus runs in the foreground and you can type Control-Z
whilst it is outputting error messages you could then attach to the process
with `gdb -p` and the process id to see where it might be. Or use `lsof -p` and the
process id to see what files are open.

Also, you can try `strace nautilus 2>/tmp/errs` which will show all the opens,
writes, and so on so you can see what was opened just before the messages
were printed. Beware, the log will be very large, but grepping for the last open might be enough.

Comment: All of the JP2s were corrupt according to `identify` but GIMP was able to open them. I saved them as '.jpg's using GIMP and ran `rm *.JP2` on the affected directory. Now the problem with that folder is fixed, and it still occurs in another folder with .JP2s. Thank you for your help @meuh!